# How to validate if one SqlServer database is the same as another database

Tags: sql-server

I have two databases, dbOne and dbTwo.
I dbTwo is based on dbOne. During a cI/CD-pipe I would like to validate if the data and/or schema is the same in dbTwo as in dbOne, if they are not the same, I would backup dbOne and restore it to dbTwo.
How would I be able to tell if dbOne and dbTwo are the same? Is there some sort of checksum or a date or anything that could be used to tell if a database had been modified?

Comment: Why not just do the backup and restore anyway? The alternatives are some quite complex dynamic SQL or to use various tools to compare schema and data.

Comment: The idea is to include the db backup as an artifact when building the application, since the db and the application makes up one version. (Fully aware of the poor design), so prevent storing a large number of dbbackups with no actual changes in our ci/cd it would be nice to only store if changes are detected. However.. when saying it.. that might end up in incomplete versions of our application.. however.. if this is possible without 3rd-party tools I would at least have the option and be able to decide later if the approach is good or not :)

Comment: You'd need to compare the data from sys.objects from each database - perhaps aggregate the required elements to compare, compute a hash and compare their hashes. You'd then need to dynamically build a select query from each table and perform an intersection `except` from each database to identify any differences in data.

Comment: There is no other possibilities to compares if two db are identical, (even when it's a copy - backup)  that to read one by one the data structures and all the rows from all the tables, beacuse some internal matadata won't never be the same (storage as an example, servername, create date...)